# extract regex from $this->request->data and store in DB cakephp

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I am using FormHelper with cakephp 2.0. I want to extract a 21 digit number from the input field BEFORE it saves to the database, and only store the number in my database.

The code I currently have is:

```
if (!empty ( $this->request->data ) && ($this->request->is('post')))
{
    preg_match("/[0-9]{21}/", $this->request->data, $field_id);
    $this->InsightId->save($field_id[0]);
}
```

The if statement is never evaluated, and it never makes it to the preg_match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$google_id` would be an array. Try `$google_id[0]`...or output it and see if the data is as you expect. Also you could use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`. Without knowing what `$input_url` is we can't really help.

Comment: The user is supposed to grab a url which contains a 21 digit number. I'm trying to store it in $input_url so that I can filter it out with preg_match and then store it in $google_id and save it to the DB

Comment: Yea, I don't know what `$input_url` is though so I can't test this. It could be `cat`, `moose`, `/cattle/12345678913456789110/test.php`, anything else? Provide an example input. I'd think the array issue would be your probably but can't be sure..

Comment: $input_url would be something like this: https://business.google.com/b/123456789123456789123/insights/i/12342562132512562/visibility?

Comment: Okay, then that should work. https://eval.in/462497 As noted though it is an array that is returned, not a string. What is `save(` expecting?

Comment: I've since changed it to $this->InsightId->save($google_id[0]); with no change. It wont update the field it's being stored in.

Comment: If the integer is getting to the save function than the issue isnt here, it is in the save function. If you echo at the save is value making it there?

Comment: My code works if it looks like this:                                                                     if (!empty ( $this->request->data ) && ($this->request->is('post')))
        {
            $this->InsightId->save($this->request->data);                                } and if I leave it as it is above ^^ it makes it to the second if statement and saves whats entered by the user but it never enters the second if statement to evaluate the $input_url code.

Comment: So the question is why is `if($this->InsightId->save($this->request->data))
    {` returning false?

Comment: That's where I'm getting stuck. I can't figure out why it can't step into and evaluate if($this->InsightId->save($this->request->data)) is this if statement even necessary?

Comment: What does `save` return?

Comment: it only returns something if I do it like this: if (!empty ( $this->request->data ) && ($this->request->is('post'))) { $this->InsightId->save($this->request->data); } and it returns the whole url. I've tried it like this: if (!empty ( $this->request->data ) && ($this->request->is('post')))
        {
            preg_match("/\d{21}/", $this->request->data, $google_id);
            $this->InsightId->save($google_id[0]);
        } but it returns false. It's like it's unable to do the preg_match with $this->request->data

Comment: Add that to your question it is hard to read. If it is hanging at `if($this->InsightId->save($this->request->data))` that line though than it isn't getting to the `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went an entirely different route than Regex for my solution. I used php explode with '/' as my delimiter. My code now looks like this:

```
if (!empty ( $this->request->data ) && ($this->request->is('post')))
   {
        $field_ids = explode('/', $this->request->data['InsightId']['field']);

        foreach($field_ids as $field_id)
        {
            if(strlen($field_id) === 21)
            {
                $this->request->data['InsightId']['field'] = $field_id;
                $this->InsightId->save($this->request->data);
            }
        }
   }
```